# MouseDoubleClick gets wrong TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, treeview

This one is really weird unless I'm missing something really basic.

I have attached an event handler to my `TreeViewItem`'s `MouseDoubleClick` event through `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
  </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Here's the event handler:

```
Private Sub TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)

  If TypeOf sender Is TreeViewItem Then
    Dim TVI = DirectCast(sender, TreeViewItem)
    MsgBox(TVI.Header)
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that `MsgBox` always shows the header text of the root node, not the node on which I double-clicked. I can't see any obvious mistake here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you're missing one of the basic weird things about a TreeView :). Not sure how I can illustrate it easily in a post, so I'll try to explain it. A TreeViewItem has sub items. When you expand the root TreeViewItem to show the sub items, all those sub TreeViewItems are inside of the parent TreeViewItem. So when you double click on a child TreeViewItem the event will bubble up to the top most item. If you look at e.OriginalSource, you'll get the actual item... sort of... you'll actually get the object you double clicked on (for example the TextBlock). You can use the well known `GetVisualAncestor<T>()` extension method to chase up to the correct TreeViewItem:

```
((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).GetVisualAncestor<TreeViewItem>()
```

Yeah, it's ugly :)...

Here is a link to a C# implementation, you'll have to find a VB version for yourself :), but its pretty trivial to port.

https://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/source/browse/branches/jon/GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop/Utilities/VisualTreeExtensions.cs?r=29

Comment: That was it! I didn't even need `GetVisualAncestor()`. My `OriginalSource` is the `TreeViewItem` itself.